# Calling exception function requires variable assignent?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, control-flow

Very new to Python, so bear with me...

Curious about the difference between calling the following two functions in the Python interpreter via Terminal (Mac OSX):

Function #1:

```
def printthis(x):
    if x == "hello":
        print "hello"
    else:
        print "Goodbye"

x = "hello"
printthis(x)
```

When I hit enter right after `printthis(x)`, it returns the print statement:

```
hello
```

Function #2:

```
def string_checker(action):
    try:
        check = isinstance(action, basestring)
        if check == True:
            return True
    except ValueError:
        print "We need a string here!"
        return None
```

However, with this function, simply doing this then hitting enter doesn't return anything:

```
action = 987
string_checker(action)
```

I have to assign this function to a variable and then print that variable to get the function to return a value, like this:

```
>>>strcheck = string_checker(action)
>>>print strcheck
None
```

or like this:

```
>>>action = "oiuy"
>>>strcheck = string_checker(action)
>>>print strcheck
True
```

What am I missing here? Why do some functions seemingly need to be assigned to a variable to call them while other functions can simply be called by writing out the function name and passing an argument to them?

Comment: What were you expecting `string_checker()` to do?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue that's confusing you is that the python repl helpfully displays values of the expression you enter, unless that value is `None`, under the assumption that you aren't interested in those, whereas the `print` statement always renders whatever you give it.  This has essentially nothing to do with function returns or assignments, and all to do with the `print` statement (or not, for simple expressions)

```
>>> def return_this(this):
...     return this
... 
>>> return_this(5)
5
>>> return_this(None)
>>> print return_this(5)
5
>>> print return_this(None)
None
>>> 5
5
>>> None
>>>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. For the purpose of trying to use the above function for debugging user input (make sure user is entering string vs integer), should I add a print statement in the ValueError exception so that there's at least an error message?